# Htacces rewrite for magento http to https for one domain of multishop

Tags: magento

We are looking for a solution for our htacces rewrite and have been looking all over the internet and could not find the solution. We have a multishop with 10 shops and are now going over at https and first want to test one shop and then do the others. We have set everything up correctly, but do not get the 301 redirect to work.

We have tried the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.be$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.be/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But with this code all pages of the other webshops will also be redirected to this domain. Can someone help us setting it up so we can start transfer to https?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the OR.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.be$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.be/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you have split each of your domains to have independent vhosts (likely) and therefore utilize a separate block for SSL and HTTP, you should think about using a Redirect 301 in the HTTP section of the vhost to reduce complexity.